# How can I make phpdoc fail on error?

Tags: php, jenkins, phpdoc

I use phpDoc to generate documentation for my PHP app, but I also love it's errors page. I like that it catches undocumented units, since I shouldn't be committing undocumented code. However, I'd like for it to trip Jenkins.

In my `./script/test` file that I use with Jenkins, I have this setup:

- phpStan
- phpUnit

If any of them fail, then Jenkins fails (non zero exit code), and I know to fix it. I'd like to add phpDoc to this mix. I'm currently using this command:

`phpdoc -d ./src/Application -t ./public/docs/phpdoc`

I see an error, but the error code that phpdoc kicks back is zero. Is there a way to have it return a non-zero exit code so Jenkins knows that it failed?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a built-in way to have the `phpdoc` executable return an exit code that tells you there are errors on the Errors report.

A hacky way to accomplish it, however, might be this:

`phpdoc .d /src/Application -t ./public/docs/phpdoc && grep "Errors " ./public/docs/phpdoc/index.html | grep ">0<"`

The last `grep` will return a `1` if the `>0<` text (indicating zero errors) is not found.  Thus your Jenkins build should recognize the returned `1` and consider it a shellscript failure.